Non-English number script for Watch Face Format
I'm trying to Implement an Android Watch Face by using Watch Face Format. I used DigitalClock xml tag show the clock. But I want render non-english number, for example ๐,๑,๒ (0 to 2 in Thai), 〇,一, 二 (0 to 2 in Japanese). I want to render these numerical in DigitalClock.
Can someone point me out to make this things happen ?

Inside DigitalClock: Localization maybe but I have my doubts

Could you please add your code with question?
